# Continuous deployment using travis and heroku - preserving some kind of state

Tags: python, django, heroku, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

#### The problem

I'm currently in the process of setting up Travis to run our tests and deploy if the tests are successfull. Which is pretty straight forward, but I don't want to deploy when these conditions are met:

```
 - The time is between 07:00 and 22:00 (workdays)
 - During the deploy the database has to migrate or elastic search has to index
```

Since a migration or an index can be quite expensive and means downtime. I'm using the heroku provider and using the `on` parameter is simple enough, however I'm struggling with the following situation:

```
 - Git push triggers new build
 - Travis correctly identifies that a deploy is not allowed
 - Deploy is skipped using the heroku provider `on` parameter
 - Build finishes
```

5 mins later

```
 - Git push triggers new build
 - Travis incorrectly identifies a deploy is allowed (this build doesn't need a migration/index but the previous build did)
 - Travis tries to deploy and production breaks
```

#### Wanted situation

So what I actually want is something like scheduled/delayed deployments. When Travis detects one of the expensive operations need to run it schedules a deployment and all subsequent builds skip deployment untill the deployment with the expensive scripts is done. That deploy should start automatically anywhere outside business hours.

---

I hope I've described it clearly, if any more information is needed please let me know!

Comment: I think you would have to use [`after_success`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/) to trigger a script of your own making, Travis's `deploy` can only deal with relatively simple cases.

Comment: That doesn't help since that still doesn't preserve the state between builds.

Comment: What state do you need to preserve? If you mean so that it just waits for the end of the working day, I think Travis will kill the build if it's idle for so long.

Comment: No, just so that subsequent builds that don't contain the migration/index change don't falsely trigger the deploy. So state as in an ENV var `NEED_MIGRATION` or something. And using a Cron Job to trigger a build outside of business hours.

Comment: Maybe you need to decouple this from Travis - use an `after_success` to deploy to a staging environment with a cron job that periodically checks that 1. there's a new build; and 2. this is a good time to deploy it.

Comment: Yeah, a colleague of mine suggested something like that (but with an API in our app), but it just feels a little workaround/hacky to me. So I was looking for a clean solution in Travis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok with the awesome help of the folks over at Travis I came up with the following solution:

1. I've activated the [CronJobs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/cron-jobs/) and set them to run daily. At the time of writing this you can't specify a time the crons run, instead they are scheduled around the time you create them. So create a cron in the middle of the night and it runs every night.
2. Let git check if there were any changes in migration/index files over the last 24h, and if so skip the deploy.
3. Check for the travis event type and only perform the index/migrations if it's the cron running.
4. Profit.

**The code**

```
deploy:
  - provider: heroku
    skip_cleanup: true
    api_key: "${HEROKU_API_KEY}"
    app: cd-test
    on:
      # Condition is: cron job + migration and/or index necessary
      condition: "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE == 'cron' && $(git log --since='yesterday 23:00' --format=oneline -- **/migrations/* **/search.py | wc -l) -gt 0"
    run:
      - "python manage.py migrate"
      - "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
      - "python manage.py index"

  - provider: heroku
    skip_cleanup: true
    api_key: "${HEROKU_API_KEY}"
    app: cd-test
    on:
      # Condition is: not cron job + no migration and/or index necessary
      condition: "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE != 'cron' && $(git log --since='yesterday 23:00' --format=oneline -- **/migrations/* **/search.py | wc -l) == 0"
    run:
      - "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```